# Calculate Weighted Average in sql for duplicate items

Tags: sql, average

**TABLE**

```
ITEM |  SKU  |  QUANT  |      ITEM LANDING
-----+-------+---------+-----------------
ABC  | A-B-C |     5   |         500  
ABC  | A-B-C |    10   |         400  
DEF  | D-E-F |     5   |         200  
GHI  | G-H-I |     6   |         300  
JKL  | J-K-L |     5   |         800  
JKL  | J-K-L |    10   |         600
```

**RESULT**

```
ITEM NAME | ITEM SKU  | QUANT  |  Weighted Average
----------+-----------+--------+---------------------
  ABC     |    A-B-C  |   15   |      433.33  
  DEF     |    D-E-F  |    5   |      200  
  GHI     |    G-H-I  |    6   |      300  
  JKL     |    J-K-L  |   15   |      666.66
```

I want to calculate weighted average for duplicate items
**((first landing *qty)+(second landing *qty))/(sum(qty)**

Comment: What is that? Please format your information, tell us what you need, and what you tried.

Comment: How `ITEM LANDING` value is getting? Please explain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT ITEMNAME, ITEMSKU, SUM(QUANT), SUM(QUANT * ITEM_LANDING) / SUM(QUANT)
FROM <YourTable>
GROUP BY ITEMNAME, ITEMSKU
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT item_name AS 'ITEM NAME',
item_sku AS ' ITEM SKU', 
SUM(quant) AS 'QUANT',
(SUM(quant*item_landing)/sum(quant)) AS 'ITEM LANDING'
FROM items
GROUP BY item_name;
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fbb70b/1)**

Comment: Depending on the sql type which is used, you need to add `item_sku` in the `GROUP BY` part as well

Comment: @schlonzo:if using `MS SQL` `item-sku` should be there in the `GROUP BY`.