# How to get weighted average for CTR in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, math, statistics, average, weighted-average

Here is what my data looks like:

[image]

I would like to see a roll up of the total `impressions`, total `clicks` and average `ctr` for a given `query`. E.g.,

[image]

Except this is just an average of the `ctr` column values; whereas I need a weighted average.

I think this SO answer [Calculate Weighted Average in sql for duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010629/calculate-weighted-average-in-sql-for-duplicate-items) is taking me most of the way there, but since this calculation involves two metrics (ie, `impressions` and `clicks`), it's a bit different.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying how the weighted average is expected to be computed in this case? What role do `impressions` and `clicks` play in the calculation?

Comment: Maybe something like `AVG(ctr * clicks / impressions)`?

Comment: What is your Mysql client ? It looks nice.